# How to configure dynamic DNS updates when using stateless IPv6 addressing?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, windows-server-2012, ipv6, dynamic-dns

I am using Server 2012 with AD/DNS/DHCP. I have successfully configured stateful DHCPv6 however this does not accomplish what I would like to achieve so I disabled it and I'm currently trying to get stateless DHCPv6 working. I wish to use stateless IPv6 addressing and have my DNS server add entries for these hosts and update them dynamically. Windows systems that are joined to the domain work great with both IPv4 and IPv6. However, I have Windows 8.1 Tablets, Android 4.4.x phones, Fedora 20, and Linux Mint machines that need IPv6 DNS capability as I have numerous services that are IPv6 compatible; and not having to deal with port forwarding, NAT, and such would be amazing.

In my DNS Forward Lookup Zone, let's say example.com, I have enabled secure/non-secure updates. I have configured scavenging and aging to mitigate any stale records. I have also configured the "Primary DNS Suffix" on the windows tablets; I'm starting with the windows devices as they will probably be easiest.

So far, with what I have tried, I have not seen a single DNS record for NON-Domain Joined Machines.

Comment: This will be very difficult without DHCPv6. Why are you not using it?

Comment: With stateless auto configuration the only device that has all the information needed to update the DNS is the client itself. Every client had to be configured to do DNS updates so this will be different for each type of client.

Comment: I was running DHCPv6 along with stateless IPv6 configured clients but they just seemed to overlook my DHCP server. I didn't turn the DHCP server off it just doesn't appear to be doing anything for devices that aren't part of the domain. I have wireshark open and it's silent when set to show only DHCPv6.

Comment: Actually, after reading the resource below, I may have gotten the Windows Tabs to work. They had to be configured with primary DNS suffixes, and running the command: [netsh interface ipv6 set interface < server_interface > adv=en managed=en other=en] on the server seemed to do the tirck. Now onto the Linux machine and to the phones. The latter may not be possible as I can't configure them with a DNS suffix... http://blogs.technet.com/b/teamdhcp/archive/2009/03/03/dhcpv6-understanding-of-address-configuration-in-automatic-mode-and-installation-of-dhcpv6-server.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have mostly figured out what needs to happen. Android and Linux systems don't report the hostname.fqdn properly for IPv6. This can supposedly be fixed however I could not get it working after days of research and bricking one Linux client. Currently it is not possible to add a DNS suffix to android phones (without rooting) so this will probably not work the way I want it too. I have all Windows machines working beautifully though.

However, and this is very important, if your router receives the DHCP request first then your client will not be configured properly via DHCP on your server. This is still causing issues and besides having a programmable router there is really no way around this to my knowledge. I have an actiontec C1000A router and its configurations are very limited. Supposedly some routers have a setting to disable DHCPv6 functions but this one does not and tries to assimilate my network. If it weren't for these few issues, IPv6 would be working perfectly. I'm sure that OS updates and future enhancements will allow these issues to be resolved.

This post was probably the most helpful:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/cbf03cb1-09d4-4ce2-a5eb-3a3a94909c2e/dhcpv6-not-giving-out-addresses-where-to-start